# How do I delay Angular doCheck execution until user's value is fully entered into input?

Tags: html, angular

I am using the follow doCheck() method to determine if the user's input has changed before processing it.

```
ngDoCheck() {
    if (this.filter.price !== this.oldPrice) {
      // this.changeDetected = true;
      console.log(`DoCheck: Price changed to "${this.filter.price}" from 
        "${this.oldPrice}"`);
      this.oldPrice = this.filter.price
    }
  }
```

The problem is ngDoCheck is called for each individual digit the user enters. I prefer to have the user complete their input before processing it like is done using debounceTime in rxjs.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're not using the FormControl's `valueChanges` observable with a `debounceTime` operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is user input coming from a FormControl I would advise subscribing to its `valueChanges` observable with a `debounceTime` operator instead. But if you insist you can also use each call of the ngDoCheck to place the next value into your own observable:

```js
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';

class YourComponent {
  private changeSubject = new Subject();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.changeSubject.pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      debounceTime(400)
    ).subscribe( value => {
      console.log('debounced value:', value);
    });
  }

  ngDoCheck() {
    this.changeSubject.next(this.filter.price);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **changes** instead of a **lifecycle hook**.

HTML:

```
<input (change)="change($event)">
```

component:

```
  change(newValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
  }
```

Comment: It is performing just as ngDoCheck

Comment: no. change is trigger when the user leave the input not for each letter typed